Making RGB tiff files from red,green,and blue bands
i have three geotiff orthomosaic images which i have processed from pix4d mapper. one is red band, one is blue band, one is green band. I have to combine these three images to form an rgb geotiff image.The rgb geotiff image should be visually accurate rgb image,which i can view with any image viewer.

What about doing what you need and have to to?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219734/using-gdal-to-merge-3-bands-to-form-a-multispectral-image
